# Is there a way to dump all the lived objects in heap memory in Node js?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, heap-memory, loopback

As title, I have encountered a memory leak problem in loopback framework on Node js.
I can't find any problem from request API call.
So I wonder that is there any way I can dump all the objects and variables in heap memory in NodeJs when the memory usage is constantly arising, so that I can find any clue in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are running a node process in a memory restricted environment, you have to make sure that you restrict the amount of memory that is allocated to Node and to V8. What may seem like a memory leak could just be a lazy garbage collection process by the V8 engine. To supervise memory usage, I recommend the npm add-on memwatch-next.

You can force V8 to perform a garbage collection by executing your node js program with in the following manner: node --expose-gc test.js

Now, within the code, you are able to call global.gc() at set time intervals when you'd like V8 to perform an old-space cleanup.

Additional information can be found here: https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/